# Get file list and pass it into cmd

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am currently getting a file list from an OpenFileDialog and adding then into a list this way

```
private void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
            Open.Filter = "RIFF/RIFX (*.Wav)|*.wav";
            Open.CheckFileExists = true;
            Open.Multiselect = true;
            Open.ShowDialog();

            LstFile.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string file in Open.FileNames)
            {
                LstFile.Items.Add(file);


            }
        }
```

How would i Get the individual file names from the list and pass them into cmd.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to make a process with arguments

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg1 arg2";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

just pass whatever arguments you want to pass in place of `arg1` and `arg2`

If you need to know how to get output from the process, just say so and I'll include that too.

you can get individual filenames by iterating over your list, just use a `foreach` loop

```
foreach(string fn LstFile.Items)
{
    //do something with fn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) to pass parameters to `Process`:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Explore.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = yourArguments;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```